# Como consultar valores de Data em uma conexão C# para excel usando OleDb?

Tags: c#, query, datagridview, oledb

Segue abaixo a linha de código

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conex = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conex);

            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" + textBox2.Text + "$] where DATA ="+ dateTimePicker1.Value , conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

tento retornar um valor fazendo busca pela Data, porem só encontro erros.
Sem aspas simples(como no codigo), retorna erro =

> ```
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando)
> na expressão de consulta 'DATA =18/12/2020 08:20:04'.'
> ```

Quando ponho aspas simples na consulta em torno da dateTimePicker da erro =

> ```
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Tipo de dados imcompatível na
> expressão de critério.'
> ```

Comment: Não, DATA é o nome da coluna os esta todas as dates, e que quero buscar os valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu banco de dados pode não está entendendo o formato da data. Normalmente se trabalha com o formato `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Inclua o método `ToString` em seu `dateTimePicker1.Value` explicitando em qual formato a data deve ser escrita na consulta.

```cs
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM  [" + textBox2.Text + "$] where DATA ="+ dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") , conn);
```

Comment: O meu banco de dados que estou usando é uma planilha do excel, o formato é dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss .

agora ele até roda, mas não retorna nenhum valor

Comment: Então o erro foi resolvido. Agora a atenção tem que ser dada aos valores do banco e do critério. Ao usar o operador igual, garanta que o valor procurado é idêntico aos que existem no banco. No caso de DateTime isso inclui até os milésimos de segundo.

Comment: Consegui, inclui um "like" na consulta para que buscasse os demais valores após a data.
Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: Legal! Se essa solução lhe ajudou contornar o erro, marque essa resposta como aceita que ela seja concluída. Abraço!